# Como Mudar o Tipo de servidor no Firebird 2.5 (– SuperServer, ClassicServer ou SuperClassic)

Tags: firebird

Como Faz para Mudar o tipo de Server no *Firebid 2.5*?
Sei que são 3 : **SuperServer**, **ClassicServer** ou **SuperClassic**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito para alterar as arquiteturas é desinstalar e instalar novamente. Isso é feito em questão de minutos e os bancos vão funcionar normalmente após.

Dependendo pode ser necessário fazer alguma configuração no servidor, mas não nos bancos.

Fonte: https://firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg25-appx-architectures.html

Comment: Que pena! poderia ser mais prático para os usuários instalar novamente da trabalho...

Comment: @EduardoMendonçadaSilva Acho que a parte "dá trabalho", é questão de ponto de vista. Mas concordo que poderia ser mais fácil.